# How are these two definitions of topology equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let ${\tau}$ be a topology on $S$ which is a set we are considering and let $P$ be a power set of $S$.

**FIRST**  **DEFINITION**

$(a):{\tau}\ ⊆ \ P$

$(b):$ Union of any subset of ${\tau}$ is in ${\tau}$.

$(c): $ Intersection of any finite subset of ${\tau}$ is in ${\tau}$.

$(d):$ $S{\in}{\tau}$

**SECOND  DEFINITION**

$(1):{\tau}\ ⊆ \ P$

$(2):$ Union of any subset of ${\tau}$ is in ${\tau}$.

$(3): $ Intersection of any two elements of ${\tau}$ is in ${\tau}$.

$(4):$ $S{\in}{\tau}$

How to prove that one implies the other?

Comment: They're not equivalent. If you add the condition that $S$ is in your topology in the second definition, they are equivalent.

Comment: btw it should be $S \in \tau$, not $S \subseteq \tau$

Comment: Corrected this, I still don't understand how $(3)$ implies $(c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(3) implies (c) by induction.

Assume (3), so that the intersection of any two elements of $\tau$ is in $\tau$.

Let $C(n)$ be the claim that the interesection of any $n$ elements of $\tau$ is in $\tau$. The hypothesis (3) is your base case $C(2)$.

Assume that $C(n-1)$ is true, and let $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ be elements of $\tau$. By the induction hypotehsis, $U\colon = U_1\cap\ldots\cap U_{n-1}$ is an element of $\tau$. By (3), the set $U\cap U_n$ is then also an element of $\tau$, but $$U\cap U_n = U_1\cap\cdots\cap U_n,$$ so this proves $C(n)$.

Comment: Why couldn't $U$ be composed of an infinite number of sets?

Comment: @Qwedfsf Because you are trying to prove that "the intersection of any two elements of $\tau$ is in $\tau$" implies that "the intersection of any finite subset of $\tau$ is in $\tau$". I assume the former, and I then want to prove the latter, which is why I take some *finite* collection $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ collection of sets in $\tau$. Then certainly $U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1}$ is also a finite collection.